# html - match width with above element automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this sample, the `main` element dimension maybe changed (now it's 240x320 defined by css). I wish the `controls` element always match the width of `main`. is it possible do it with css or need to change that from javascript?

```css
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5e0e0;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.keys {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-screen">
  <video class="video" id="main" autoplay></video>
  <div id="controls" class="icon">
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="home" name="home"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="power" name="power"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="menu" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="volumedown" name="volume-low"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="volumeup" name="volume-high"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few ways CSS can do this. One way is to make your center-screen container a fixed width and add `margin: 0 auto` so it stays centered. Remove fixed width from the video element.

Then remove the `align-items` property since stretch is the default and what you want.

```
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5e0e0;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.keys {
  height: 40px;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/z06dbLqf/9/)

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra wrapper and it would be easy

```css
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5e0e0;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:block; /*added this to remove white space*/
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.keys {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-screen">
  <div>
    <video class="video" id="main" autoplay></video>
    <div id="controls" class="icon">
      <ion-icon class="keys" id="home" name="home"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon class="keys" id="power" name="power"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon class="keys" id="menu" name="menu"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon class="keys" id="volumedown" name="volume-low"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon class="keys" id="volumeup" name="volume-high"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Comment: BTW, how to remove the top little gap? I want the video box match the top line exactly!

Comment: @lucky1928 `body {margin:0}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your could do it likes this:
Add the dimensions to the .center-screen and then scale video and controls relatively to it. Depending on how your actual content is structured, this might be different, but we can't say as long as you dont show us :)

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5e0e0;
}

.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 240px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.keys {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-screen">
  <video class="video" id="main" autoplay></video>
  <div id="controls" class="icon">
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="home" name="home"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="power" name="power"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="menu" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="volumedown" name="volume-low"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon class="keys" id="volumeup" name="volume-high"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, since the dimension will change after video load, so add dimension to center-screen maybe not proper way!

Comment: Hard to find the right solution for you, if you're only sharing half the info :) however, you could just set the video height to auto and remove the fixed height and width from the center-screen and the rest will scale automatically. but you have enough answers already :) good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the video and controls elements in a div, set the width of that new div to whatever pixel value width you want, and have the inner elements ( video and controls ) have 100% width.

pseudo-markup :

```
  <style> 
    .wrapper { width : 240px; }
     video, .controls { width: 100%; }
    </style>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <video>
        <div class="controls>
    <div>
```